# ESNext: What's the purpose of the `async` keyword?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

I've been using the `async`/`await` keywords a lot lately with JavaScript Promise objects and I love it, but I don't understand what the purpose of the `async` keyword really is.

Why is it necessary to use the `async` keyword for functions that use `await`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions marked `async` always return a promise (as opposed to regular functions):

> When an `async` function is called, it returns a `Promise`. When the `async` function returns a value, the `Promise` will be resolved with the returned value.  When the `async` function throws an exception or some value, the `Promise` will be rejected with the thrown value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description

Comment: Just to clarify, async is a syntactic sugar. It saves you some typing needed to handle promises and stuff. But most importantly, **async allows you to use await keyword within the function**. You cannot await anything from a non-async function.

Comment: @netchkin _"async is a syntactic sugar"_ and _"async allows you to use await keyword within the function."_ contradict each other.

Comment: @zeroflagL: good point! I have indeed misused the term "syntactic sugar". What I meant was it saves you some typing if you'd write promise-based code manually.